# how to ignore quote in fscanf

Tags: c++, stdio

I have problem with read string from text file. In file there is data in this format:

something="test"

And I want to read string between quotes. So in my program I do:

```
fscanf(fil,"language=\"%s[^\"]",data);
```

or

```
fscanf(fil,"language=\"%s\"",data);
```

but I always get test" in variable data. How can I ignore the second quote? Except putting space before in file. I want exactly that format in text file.

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: The `s` doesn't belong there in the first snippet.

Comment: data is array of chars char data[20] so I think s is good format.

Comment: `fscanf` can't back up, so when it hits `%s` in the format it reads an entire string, which is all characters until a whitespace.

Comment: `%s[^\"]` ===> `%[^\"]`.

Comment: See what @n.m. noted, and [review the documentation for `std::scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). And don't feel bad. You're not the first person to mash together set and string formatted input, and you certainly won't be the last.

Comment: so there is no method except put space before "?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. This is a dupe of many, *many* different previous asks, but its somewhat painful to find as the titles and contexts are generally so divergent they don't search well. [See live example here](http://ideone.com/WyNERQ). I'll spend a little time looking for an appropriate dupe unless someone else beats me to it.

Comment: Why are you using fscanf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to think too deeply about formatting strings you could always read in the full string than take out the sub string that you want.

**Example:**

The following code searches through `str` for the first `"` and last `"` and puts the substring in `strNew`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;  //used for ease but not the best to use in actual code.

int main()
{
  string str = "variable=\"name\"";
  cout << str << endl;
  int first = str.find("\"");
  int last = str.find_last_of("\"");
  string strNew = str.substr (first + 1, last - first -1);
  cout << strNew << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that is what I need. Now it works exactly how I want.